# Can the Browser 'Forward' Button be Set from HTML?

Tags: html

Example: At the bottom of the StackOver Questions page are a bunch of page numbers (1,2,3...), enclosed in a set of *prev* and *next* buttons. Clicking *next* repeatedly will bring me to, say page 5, at which point I will have:

- The page's *prev* button will be set to 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=4'
- The *Back* button on my Browser will have the same value.
- The page's *next* button will be set to 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=6'
- The *Forward* button on my Browser - won't be set to anything.

Obviously, if I hit the *Back* button on the Browser, then *Forward* will have a value, pointing to the URL for page 5 - but not otherwise.

Is there any way, from HTML (plus Javascript), to set the value of the Browser's *Forward* button? Or is this one of those things that HTML is simply forbidden to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are possibly looking for [custom links](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.1.2), although I am not aware of any major browser that utilizes them.

Comment: Opera uses them with its fast-forward button - for example on Google search results fast-forward will take you to the next page.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat That's right, I had forgotten about that. There is a plugin for firefox that utilizes all of the rel tags as well.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible.

Besides, back and forwards are about where the user has been, not a specific logical sequence of pages.